# Huge amount of same textured quads

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I want to draw huge amount of same textured quads (tile mapping). Textured quads will have same size and same texture coordinates but different coordinates on screen.

I use `VertexBuffer` and `DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, ...)`

If quads are located one after another I can use texture repeating (set texture coordinates > 1) and only 6 vertices in `VertexBuffer`.

If quads are at different position I create 6 vertices for each quad in `VertexBuffer` and this method has poor performance (less than 60 FPS starting from 1500000 vertices on powerfull computer).

`SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` is used for compatibility purposes.

Is there any better approach to draw huge amount of small same textured quads in different position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think that `SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` is a likely suspect for the poor performance - have you benchmarked with/without this flag?

Comment: `HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` solves situation and gives constant 60 FPS ( 100+ FPS without VSync) but application should be able to work smooth also on hardware which support only `SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` for instance on old Intel chipsets. I wonder is there any other solution than creating vertex for each quad in `VertexBuffer` (as already mentioned quad size and texture coordinates are same, so basically only position on screen differs).

Comment: You could work with two vertex-streams. One for the quad and one with the positions. In the vertexshader you combine them for the right positioning. Do you render a tiled plane (2D or 3D?) or blocks like minecraft or whats the purpose?

Comment: I render tiled 2D plane. Will 2 vertex streams help? I dont update vertex buffer every frame only after creation (static position) and according to `MS 2010 Performance Analyzer` most CPU is used at `Present`.

Comment: If all is static I don't think 2 streams are helpful, it's used to reduce drawcalls or usage of the bandwidth. Do you see always all the tiles? (It would be nice to hear what do you want to achieve with the tiles, so I haven't to guess how your scene looks like) If not you should google for "viewing frustum culling" (with a quadtree probably in your case): The fastest triangle is the one who isn't drawed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using quadtree approach

Comment: Thank you for answer. I would appreciate if you provide some more information about this approach (links).

Comment: Quadtree is mainly used for terrain LOD (level of detail) rendering apps. The idea is to show only relevant quads depending on their distance from camera. Please check the following google search results:
https://www.google.bg/#sclient=psy-ab&q=quadtree+multiple+texture+quads&oq=quadtree+multiple+texture+quads&gs_l=hp.3...637.12250.0.12375.33.31.1.1.1.0.210.4105.0j30j1.31.0...0.0...1c.1.15.psy-ab.1lo_UVH9ERQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47380653,d.ZWU&fp=87f495de9fe5a5f6&biw=1280&bih=648
If you have more questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you need so many same texture quads? if you only need to render a 2D plane, i think one quad is enough.